# In a oracle procedure to get the maximum number from Varchar data type field having a prefix

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table called ORG, In which I have a field called ORG_ID, I need to get the maximum value from the ORG ID for a specific prefix. For example

Table ORG

| ORG_ID | ORG_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| AB1 | Apple |
| AB2 | Google |
| HQ1 | Microsoft |
| AB3 | Tesla |
| HQ2 | Amazon |

Now, I want to get the maximum numeric value associated with the prefix AB, I am using below

```
select max(ORG.ORG_ID)
from ORG
where ORG_ID like 'AB'
```

It returns `AB3` I can use regular expression to get the numeric value 3.
My concern is does the above select query always guarantee the max numeric value with the sequence AB.

code

```
DECLARE
      v_max_number  NUMBER;
       v_max_org_id  VARCHAR2 (20);
       v_max_var     VARCHAR2 (20);
  
       CURSOR curb IS
          SELECT org_id, name
            FROM tableb
          FOR UPDATE;
 
      cbr           curb%ROWTYPE;
      i             NUMBER := 1;
      
   BEGIN
      SELECT MAX (tablea.org_id)
        INTO v_max_org_id
        FROM tablea
       WHERE org_id LIKE 'AB%';
 
      SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (v_max_org_id, '\d+') INTO v_max_number FROM DUAL;
 
      SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (v_max_org_id, '\D+') INTO v_max_var FROM DUAL;
 
      -- For Loop to write data to Table B
      OPEN curb;
 
      LOOP
         FETCH curb INTO cbr;
 
        EXIT WHEN curb%NOTFOUND;
 
         v_max_org_id := v_max_var || TO_CHAR (v_max_number + i);
 
         UPDATE tableb
            SET org_id = v_max_org_id
          WHERE CURRENT OF curb;
 
         i := i + 1;
      END LOOP;
   END;
```

Comment: This query doesn't return `AB3`, because `ORG_ID like 'AB'` is the same as `ORG_ID = 'AB'`. Please show your code with regular expressions

Comment: hi @astentx, I had added the code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> My concern is does the above select query always guarantee the max numeric value with the sequence AB.

The "above query" is

```
select max(ORG.ORG_ID)
from ORG
where ORG_ID like 'AB'
```

---

So, does it return MAX numeric value? I don't think so:

```
SQL> with test (id) as
  2    (select 'AB5'    from dual union all
  3     select 'AB15'   from dual union all
  4     select 'AB1280' from dual             --> 1280 is MAX (compared to 5 and 15)
  5    )
  6  select max(id)
  7  from test
  8  where id like 'AB%'
  9  /

MAX(ID
------
AB5                   --> this is what your query returns

SQL>
```

Based on sample data in this (and previous) question you posted, consider

```
SQL> with test (id) as
  2    (select 'AB5'    from dual union all
  3     select 'AB15'   from dual union all
  4     select 'AB1280' from dual
  5    )
  6  select max(to_number(regexp_substr(id, '\d+$'))) result
  7  from test
  8  where id like 'AB%'
  9  /

    RESULT
----------
      1280

SQL>
```